# UploadedFile and getting multiple file uploads?

Tags: xpages

I've created an XPage with a call to a Java class in the `beforePageLoad` event that takes over.

In the Java class I want to receive one or multiple file uploads (through a HTML form with multiple file upload controls all with the same name `file`).

This works:

```
Map parameters = request.getParameterMap();
UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile) parameters.get("file");
```

This does not work:

```
Map parameters = request.getParameterMap();
UploadedFile[] files = (UploadedFile[]) parameters.get("file");
```

So my questions is: How can I get to more than the first uploaded file from the Java class and loop through and process each of them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, your `Map parameters` contains all UploadedFiles then you can get them all with

```java
for (Entry entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("parameter: " + entry.getKey());
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof UploadedFile) {
        UploadedFile file = entry.getValue();
        // work with file
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Knut. I actually considered this for a moment but wanted an easier approach if possible. All of my files are uploaded in the field 'file' so I assumed that it was possible to get a list of UploadedFile. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: This is not possible. I you have the same field multiple times, only the first one will processed. The server only "extracts" one file per request.

Comment: So I can't get a list of all uploaded files which have the same field name, right?! So I need to use a loop like Knut suggested and only then I can get to the individual files which has been uploaded with the same field name, right?! Or are you [@SvenHasselbach] saying that only one file can be uploaded at a time?

Comment: Would it be possible to use Apache Commons FileUpload API for parsing the files instead of relying on IBM's request parser?

Comment: If Sven is right then my assumption is wrong and suggested code won't work. But, you can check that very easy: just test suggested loop. If you don't get more then one UploadedFile then it is not just about reading parameters in a different way. Then you have to look for another approach. Maybe, you can show us the upload part of your XPages you use so far.

Comment: @KimHansen: you can upload multiple files in different HTTP form fields, or you can try the *multiple* attribute of a file input.